# Как правильно нарисовать составной компонент?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день ,короче верстаем для андроида дизайн , и тут есть компонент для recycle-ла это карточки внутри с 10 текстами 2 фотками.У нас получилась прям иерархия конейтнеров и компонентов.Срисовать смогли но насколько это прально ?прям не по себе как это прально сделать ?у нас внутри одного льяута по 5-7 льяутов вышло.Грешно даже както

Comment: Все с опытом приходит :) Каких-то универсальных правил нет. Нужно смотреть на дизайн.

Comment: [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) вам в помощь...

Comment: @mit ты издеваешься или как ?))))

Comment: Почему издевается? Как вариант, но нужно видеть дизайн.